# jquery calculator bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, calculator

I'm using the jquery calculator plugin but I'm running into a problem and was wondering if there was a work-around. I have a form that has more than 8 iterations in it to calculate. Once I get to #9 it breaks with no error showing.

```
$(function() {
      $('input[name^=sum]').keyup(function() {
            var sum1 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum1]').val()); // Or parseInt if integers only
            var sum2 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum2]').val());
            var sum3 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum3]').val());
            var sum4 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum4]').val());
            var sum5 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum5]').val());
            var sum6 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum6]').val());
            var sum7 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum7]').val());
            var sum8 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum8]').val());
            var sum9 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum9]').val());
            var sum10 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum10]').val());
            $('#totalSum').val(sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4 + sum5 + sum6 + sum7 + sum10);
      });
});
$(function() {
        $('input#totalSum').blur(function() {
            var amt = parseFloat(this.value);
            $(this).val('' + amt.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
```

Comment: all values exist?  and how do you know it "breaks at #9", or rather, did you not present the problem correctly?  I assume you mean you can only add UP TO eight numbers in a single statement?

Comment: In what way does it break? Do you have a fiddle demonstrating the issue? Is it possible that the error is related to your total sum not including `sum8` and `sum9`? While I suspect that's the issue, it's hard to know without more information about the error you experience.

Comment: yes it adds up to #8 then when i add sum9 in $('#totalSum').val(sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4 + sum5 + sum6 + sum7 + sum10);
 all i get is the value NAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug. Make sure to default your inputs to `0`, otherwise `parseFloat` will attempt to parse an empty string which returns `NaN` (Not a Number). You can do this either by setting a `value="0"` attribute for your inputs, or by doing something along the lines of:

```
var sum1 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum1]').val(), 10)  || 0;
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/fqfyL/

On another note, you could greatly simplify your logic by iterating through your inputs instead of having to write a line of code for each one. Here's another fiddle to demonstrate that concept: http://jsfiddle.net/fqfyL/1/

Finally, I'm not sure which "jQuery calculator plugin" you're using (there's only about a bazillion of them) but none of the code I posted in either fiddle uses a plugin. It's all just plain jQuery/JavaScript. If you're still having problems with your "jQuery calculator plugin", please post a link to the author's site so we know which one to help you with.

Comment: ok thank you thought I was going out of my mind. and ty for the tip!! this will make this form work perfectly.